# How to remove NaN when there's no value entered in a field while calculating using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    var discount_amount = parseFloat($('#amtdelivary').val());
    var other_discount = parseFloat($('#othdis').val());
    calculate_total_amount=Math.round(sub_total1 + tax_amount +discount_amount-other_discount);
    $('#fnltot').val(calculate_total_amount);
```

When I keep the other_discount text field empty, its showing a NaN. If the text field is 0 its functioning accurately but when the field is set to empty, its resulting in NaN.

```
    if(isNaN(other_discount)){
                other_discount=0;
            }
```

I tired these but its not working.

Comment: Your `if(isNaN(other_discount)){ other_discount=0; }` code should work.

Answer (score 3):

Append `|| 0` after your `parseFloat` like below. If value returned as `NaN` or any `falsy` value then it will return `0` instead of `NaN`.

```
var discount_amount = parseFloat($('#amtdelivary').val()) || 0;
var other_discount = parseFloat($('#othdis').val()) || 0;
```

```js
var discount_amount = parseFloat();
console.log(discount_amount);

// Your if condition should also work.
if(isNaN(discount_amount)) {
  discount_amount = 0;
}
console.log(discount_amount);

// Alternate and single line solution.
discount_amount = parseFloat() || 0;
console.log(discount_amount);
```

Answer (score 2):

In java script simple you can pass parameter in given function if true then NUMBER and if false then NOT A NUMBER.

```
  function IsNaN(value) {
        if (Number.isNaN(parseInt(value)) === true)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can further simplify your code as `function IsNaN(value) { return Number.isNaN(parseInt(value)); }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (other_discount == '' || other_discount ==  null) {
    other_discount = 0
}
```